# Request to rename [macosx] → [macos]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retagging

The current name of Apple's desktop operating system is [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS). On this site, the tag [macosx](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macosx) is used to refer to that ("Mac OS X" was the original name of the operating system").

But other Stack Exchange sites use the tag [macos](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos), including:

- [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos) (Apple)
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos)
- [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos) (Gaming)
- [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos)
- [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos)
- [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos)

So I would like to request that we rename [macosx](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macosx) → [macos](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos), thus making us consistent with the other sites. We can keep the former tag as a synonym.

Additionally, we should have [osx](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) as a synonym, since another former name for the operating system is "OS X".